# Keyboard accessible Facebook send button

Tags: facebook, accessibility

The [Facebook send button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) doesn't seem to be keyboard accessible. When I tab to the send button, there is no indication that the button is focused, and hitting enter doesn't have the same affect as clicking the button.

Is there a way to make the Facebook send button keyboard accessible?

PS. the [tweet button](http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton), which seems to be done in a similar way doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: I should mention: this happens in Chrome 12, but not Firefox 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log a bug with Facebook.  The content of the send button is inside an iframe so you realistically won't have access to make changes to it due to cross-domain restrictions.

Comment: Thanks OffBySome, you're right. I ended up using sharer.php like stackoverflow does.